# Google/Eclipse windowbuilder - how does it work?

Tags: java, eclipse, windowbuilder

When you design a GUI window, does it save its own definition file anywhere for your GUI layout, or it just creates the JAVA for your GUI and then it uses that JAVA file to load your GUI layout again?

Answer (score 2):

WindowBuilder just creates a .java-file with the code.
If you open the GUI file in Eclipse and whenever you switch to Design, WindowBuilder parses the code and creates sort of a preview. You can then make changes and they will be transferred to the code. There are no additional files involved, as far as I'm aware.

You can also try to open existing files containing GUI code by using Open With -> WindowBuilder Editor. Afterwards Eclipse will be aware that it's a GUI file and you can always switch between Source and Design view.

I don't know how it reacts to a GUI which is composed of several classes/files, however.

Comment: Is it just for UI? what about if i want to design my events visually?

Comment: WindowBuilder provides some features for hooking up events. You should just try it out and see for yourself. The Help pages will help guide you through the features; in Eclipse, use *Help* > *Help Contents* and then open the **WindowBuilder Pro User Guide** chapter.

Comment: I'm not sure how you want do design your events visually. I think WindowBuilder has no such feature.

Comment: @Sebastian_H "Easily add controls using drag-and-drop, add event handlers to your controls" <--- add event handlers to your controls? what exactly does it do here? technically.

Comment: @001 Not much actually. You can choose what kind of event you want to have on your control, say an ActionListener. WindowBuilder then just adds component.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {...}). He then jumps into the source and you have to do the rest yourself, i.e. handle your event. If you want a dialog to pop up, you have to write the necessary code yourself as far as I'm aware. They have a feature called visual inheritance, which can inherit from things like JDialog. Maybe you could design the dialog separately and then just inherit it, but I haven't looked deeper into that feature.